# What can be said about the mass and charge of two electrically charged particles simultaneously fired horizontally?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, electric-fields, mass, charge

[image]

So, the diagram above shows two electrically charged particles, X and Y, being simultaneously fired horizontally with different speeds into an electric field at point P. The horizontal initial velocities are orthogonal to the external electric field. I want to know whether the masses and charges are the same or different.

Here's my understanding:

The magnitude of the electric force on a positively charged particle
$$F=q\cdot E$$

Acceleration of a positively charged particle
$$m\cdot a=q\cdot E$$
$$a=\frac{q\cdot E}{m}$$

Parabolic path equation of a particle launched horizontally
$$y=\frac{a}{2 v_i^2}x^2$$

Substituting the acceleration expression into the path equation
$$y=\frac{q\cdot E}{2 m v_i^2}x^2$$

According to the diagram, the parabolic path traced by particle X would have a larger leading coefficient compared to particle Y. $(q_X>0\text{ and }q_Y>0)$

$$\frac{q_X\cdot E}{2 m_X v_X^2}>\frac{q_Y\cdot E}{2 m_Y v_Y^2}\to \frac{q_X}{m_X v_X^2}>\frac{q_Y}{m_Y v_Y^2}$$
$$\text{(where }v_X\text{ and }v_Y\text{ are the initial horizontal velocities)}$$

From this result, we cannot conclude whether one particle is more massive than the other particle. Also, we cannot conclude whether one particle has a more positive charge than the other particle. Is that a fair assessment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assume that the diagram implies that the particles are at the arrowheads at the same instant in time, then **yes**, you do have enough information to say something about $q/m$.

The shape of the parabolas is basically irrelevant, since you do not have any meaningful information about the horizontal velocities.

However, you do know how the vertical component of the trajectory behaves as a function of time:
$$
y(t) = \frac12 a t^2 = \frac12 \frac{q}{m} t^2.
$$
The particle at Y has advanced more in the horizontal direction, which means that it started off with a higher horizontal velocity, but it has also moved higher in the vertical direction, which means that its $q/m$ is higher than the particle at X.

However, you cannot conclude from this what the relationships are of the bare charges and masses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The horizontal velocity of each particle is unaffected by the electric field, so we know that Y has a greater initial speed than X. Y also has a greater vertical deflection than X (assuming the ends of the tracks give their positions at the same time) so we can conclude that the charge to mass ratio of Y is greater than that of X. But we cannot conclude anything about the particle’s separate masses or charges.